# Lengths of paths through Conway’s Game of Life

Tags: recreational-mathematics, directed-graphs, cellular-automata

This question is inspired by the following challenge from CodeGolf.SE: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/251510/88765.

Given positive integer $N$, we can consider a version of Conway’s game of life restricted to the $N\times N$ grid. Namely, given a state $s$, viewed as a function from $[N]^2$ to $\{0,1\}$, we define its updated state $s’= T(s)$ so that $s’(v) =1$ if there are exactly three $u$ at $L_\infty$ distance $1$ from $v$ with $s(u)=1$ or $s(v)=1$ and there are exactly two $u$ at $L_\infty$ distance $1$ from $v$ with $s(u)=1$.

Anyways, we can define a directed graph $G_N$ on the set of these states, with an edge from each state $s$ to its updated state $T(s)$. Let $L(N)$ denote the length of the longest directed path in $G_N$. Let $L’(N)$ be the length of longest directed path that doesn’t intersect a directed cycle.

Is the asymptotic growth of $L(N),L’(N)$ known? Also, is it possible for $L(N)$ to equal $L(N+1)$ or $L’(N)$ to equal $L’(N+1)$? In the latter case, this suggests the aforementioned Code Golf challenge can’t go on forever with perfect play (though they work with a slightly different variant I believe).

Comment: I don't have an answer other than "the asymptotic growth is really, really, fast". See [this forum post](https://conwaylife.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=&p=149066#p149066) for a demonstration of the fact that $L(111) \geq {}^{15}10$ (that's tetration, not exponentiation). I haven't done a proper analysis, but the construction used there could probably be used to show something like $L(N) \geq {}^{N/8}10$ for large $N$. This all assumes that, like in the CodeGolf challenge, the pattern is allowed to evolve outside of the $N \times N$ grid after the first timestep.

Comment: If the pattern is not allowed to evolve outside of the original $N \times N$ grid then of course you can't have this sort of blowup: you trivially get $L(N) \leq 2^{N^2}$ since there are only that many configurations possible.

Comment: hm, well since it grows very fast, I’m reasonably convinced the second case shouldn’t occur. getting good bounds on the growth still seems interesting me. I am in fact forbidding evolution outside the $N \times N$ grid, which means thing *can* be calculated in finite time (no halting problem/busy beaver shenanigans).

Comment: If you want to restrict to the $N \times N$ square, then I'm pretty sure that the asymptotic growth is $\Theta(2^{N^2})$. I already argued the upper bound. For a lower bound, you could construct a pattern like [O(sqrt(log(t))](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/O(sqrt(log(t)))) that is programmed to count in binary in a 2D region of the $N \times N$ square and then self-destruct once it is full. That wiki page is light on details, but this construction is done in more detail in Section 9.7.2 of [our book](https://conwaylife.com/book/).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: Are you sure it is $\Theta(2^{N^2})$ and not $2^{\Theta(N^2)}$?

Comment: I'll also add to Nathaniel Johnston's first comment that without the restriction to the square the growth is faster than any recursive function by the 0e0p construction of Goucher.

Comment: @VilleSalo - You're quite right; it's $2^{\Theta(N^2)}$.

Comment: Actually $\Theta(2^{N^2})$ would imply surjectivity.